# validating true or false from SignalR server response - if it is possible to manipulate it?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, signalr

this is my ValidateObject:

```
    Status: @if (Model.Connected == false)
    {
        <img src="/icons/wifi_off.svg" height="45" width="45" /><span>Offline, brak połączenia z portem COM</span>
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="/icons/wifi_on.svg" height="45" width="45" /><span>Online, połączono z portem COM</span>
    }
```

and i want trigger 'false' with response from server. Does someone know how and if it is possible to stick it with SignalR connection response?

```
switch(informations[0]){
case "Status":
status.InnerHTML = informations[1];
break
}
```